# Text size that fit to the boundary

Tags: android, text, textview

is possible to find the exact text size the fit to the exact height and width. 
The string i need to fit is static.I tried some library but none of them work fine. I need to so precisely. In ios there is an API called `boundingRectWithSize` which return the exact value. does android have anything like this.

The lib i tryed

[AutoFitTextView](https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/AutoFitTextView)

```
  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams parms = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
      (int) calculatedWidth, (int) calculatedHeight);
      txt.setLayoutParams(parms);
```

Comment: may i knwwhy the down vote

Comment: Guess: The lack of care shown by the amount of typos